# Getting struck in infinite loop in multi thread program using cpp

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, compiler-optimization, volatile, infinite

I have a shared boolean array of size equal to number of threads. All threads will take  a copy of the corresponding element of the  array based on index. All threads except one(which negates the value of shared boolean array) goes into a while loop comparing its local copy with shared one. Whenever there is a change , it is supposed to exit the loop. But all threads remain struck in the loop forever. I made sure that the share values are updated correctly. Even tried declaring the shared array as volatile. But it didn't work out. What am i missing here?

Comment: It appears from your description that the threads are monitoring a copy of the boolean variable associated with their thread except for the one thread that modifies all values in its copy of the array of booleans. No thread sees any change in its local copy because it is only a local copy. The array must be shared, not local to each thread.

Comment: Sorry if I have not made it clear. The array is accessible to all the threads. One thread alone modifies all the elements of the array. Other threads are supposed to exit the loop after the modification by comparing its local copy with shared .

Comment: Any shared data has to either be atomic or synchronized with muteness. Volatile won’t be enough to get achieve correct behavior.

Comment: post your code; or a reduced version of your code which demonstrates the problem.